# Why Bootstrap background and text classes are not making changes in my react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to making a similar design as below:

[image]

The code I have typed in looks like this:

The parent component:

```
<div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <Contactbanner className="col-md-4 col-sm-1" contactInfo1="LESS THAN " contactInfo2="30 MIN" contactInfo3=" ARRIVAL" />
                <Contactbanner className="col-md-4 col-sm-1 text-warning bg-dark" contactInfo1="0(455) " contactInfo2="456 56 56" contactInfo3="" />
                <Contactbanner className="col-md-4 col-sm-1" contactInfo1="" contactInfo2="LIVE 24/7" contactInfo3=" SERVICE" />
            </div>
 </div>
```

The child component:

```
class Contactbanner extends React.Component{ 
render(){
return(
        <div className="col-md-4 p-2">
            <p className="text-center">{this.props.contactInfo1}<strong>{this.props.contactInfo2}</strong>{this.props.contactInfo3}</p>
        </div>
   )
 }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is with background color and text color. In the parent component, second time when I called the child component, I have added the bootstrap class name as "text-warning bg-dark" but there is no change over the browser. However, col-md-6 and col-sm-12 are working fine.

I inspected it and the element looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to make this component without using props but then the background and text colors are working and not when using props.

Thing I want to understand is whether there is anything wrong with my code or is this the way react bootstrap works when props are passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the className to the child component.  Contactbanner  component renders a div but when you assign className to Contactbanner  component you also need to pass it to the return jsx value of Contactbanner component.

like this.

```
class Contactbanner extends React.Component{ 
render(){
return(
        <div className={this.props.className}>
            <p className="text-center">{this.props.contactInfo1}<strong>

{this.props.contactInfo2}</strong>{this.props.contactInfo3}</p>
        </div>
   )
 }
}
```

By this way you can use className value that you pass to this component like:

```
<Contactbanner className="col-md-4 col-sm-1 text-warning bg-dark" contactInfo1="0(455) " contactInfo2="456 56 56" contactInfo3="" />
```

Comment: <Contactbanner className="col-md-4 col-sm-1 text-warning bg-dark" contactInfo1="0(455)" /> here, className should also be a props like contactInfo1. Thank you, the code is working as I wanted it to. But I don't understand why col-md-6 has worked but not the colors when not passed it as props, please explain

Comment: Because you are using className="col-md-4 p-2" in the Contactbanner div. Actualy this className not comming from Containerbanner prop, it is comming from div which is inside the Containerbanner.